# Evaluating $f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{f(z)\theta(z)^{'}}{\theta(z)-\theta(x)}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

Take $\theta(z)$ and $f(z)$ to be analytic functions on and inside $C$, Why does this equality hold:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{f(z)\theta(z)^{'}}{\theta(z)-\theta(x)}dz$$

Trying the  substitution $u=\theta(z)$,$dw=\theta(z)^{'}$,$v=\theta(x)$:
$$\oint_C\frac{f(z)\theta(z)^{'}}{\theta(z)-\theta(x)}dz=\oint_C\frac{f(z)}{w-v}dw$$
And I can't express $z$, that's not the approach maybe.

Comment: It is not true in general, if the equation (in $y$ for fixed $x$) $\theta(y)=\theta(x)$ has a solution different from $y=x$. In general, you may evaluate the integral by applying residues formula.

Answer (score 0):

This may help although I am not certain of it, so mathematical expertise is needed.Expand the terms in the denominator and numerator of the expression under the integral:
$$\frac{(f(x)+f^{'}(x)(z-x)+\dots)(\theta^{'}(x)+\theta^{''}(x)(z-x)+\dots)}{\theta^{'}(x)(z-x)+\frac{\theta^{''}(x)}{2!}(z-x)^2+\dots}=$$

$$=\frac{f(x)}{(z-x)}+\underbrace{\frac{(f^{'}(x)+\frac{f^{''}(x)}{2!}(z-x)+\dots)(1+\theta^{''}(x)(z-x)+\dots)}{1+\frac{\theta^{''}(x)}{\theta^{'}(x)2!}(z-x)+\frac{\theta^{'''}(x)}{\theta^{'}(x)3!}(z-x)^2+\dots}}_{\text{this term is analytic at z=x}}$$

$f(x)$ is the residue of $\frac{f(z)\theta^{'}(z)}{\theta(z)-\theta(x)}$. In the case that the equation $\theta(z)=\theta(x)$ has a single root $z= x$